# Long text resizing column automatically

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I'm retrieving data from my BD and trying to show it on my grid. The problem is when I have a long text:

[image]

As you can see in the image, "bbbb..." makes the columns to resize and it gets messy. I've tried to implement MANY of the solutions from SO using text wrapping but with no success i.e. [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WordBreakWrapping.htm).

Here is my code:

```
$("#grid_user").jqGrid({    
    url: 'user.jsp',
    datatype: 'json',
    pager: '#pager_user',
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
    autoencode: true,
    height: 250,
    autowidth: true,
    gridview: true,.
    viewrecords: true,.
    caption: "Usuários",
    colNames:['Código','Nome','Perfil','Ativo','Data Inclusão','Login','Senha','Confirma Senha','Email','Grupos','Grupos'],
    colModel:[                                    
        {name:'id', width:100, sortable:false, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }},
        {name:'name', width:120, editable: true, editrules:{required:true}},
        {name:'profile', width:80, editable: true, edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:{ADMINISTRADOR:'Administrador',GESTOR:'Gestor',EXECUTOR:'Executor'}}, editrules:{required:true},sortable:false},
        {name:'active', width:40, editable: true, edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:{1:'Sim',2:'Não'}}, editrules:{required:true},sortable:false},     
        {name:'creationDate', width:80, sortable:false, sorttype:"date", datefmt: 'd/M/Y', editable: false},
        {name:'login', width:120, sortable:false, editable: true, editrules:{required:true}},  
        {name:'password', width:80, sortable:false, editable: true, hidden:true, edittype:'password', editrules:{edithidden:true, required:true, custom:true, custom_func:validatePassword}},
        {name:'confirmPassword', width:80, sortable:false, editable: true, hidden:true, edittype:'password', editrules:{edithidden:true, required:true}},
        {name:'email', width:150, sortable:false, editable: true, editrules:{required:true, email:true}},
        {name:'groups', width:80, sortable: false, editable: false, hidden: true},
        {name:'groupDescription', width:200, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{ rows:"3", cols:"21", readonly: 'readonly' }}
    ]});
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
        word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ and CSS3 */
        white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 */
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
        white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
        overflow: hidden;
        height: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 3px
    }
```

How can I set the column with a fixed width, so that the text doesn't mess it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
{
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */ 
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */ 
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */ 
white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */ 
word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */ 
word-break: break-all; 
white-space: normal; 
}
```

Comment: I tried ´word-wrap: break-word´ but it just takes effect if I have space between words. For a single-lined word it doesn't work

Comment: If I set display:block into .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td, my table looks like it has been smashed up in a blender

Comment: or on td set div and inside div write your text

Comment: I don't know how to insert a div into td since it's created by jqgrid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62632/discussion-between-harutyun-abgaryan-and-lucasdc).